# FTP linked service does not support sink ADF

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to copy files from Blob Storage into a purge folder in FTP.

The problem I am facing is that the linked service in sink dataset which is the FTP does not support sink.

Is there a way to fix this or maybe a possible work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no other way available Sink is not supported in FTP. You have to use SFTP.